# Quickbooks Webservice Connector not connecting to python web service

Tags: python, quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc, qbwc

I am trying to connect Quickbooks Webservice Connector to a python webservice but the connection is not being established. I think the problem is with my .qwc file. Below is the code for the .qwc file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
    <AppName>QBWCService</AppName>
    <AppID>IDTMKV</AppID>
    <AppURL>http://localhost:8181/TroubleshootWebServiceFS</AppURL>
    <AppDescription></AppDescription>
    <AppSupport>http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/</AppSupport>
    <UserName>username</UserName>
    <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A9E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
    <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-967DE1613D20}</FileID>
    <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
    <Style>Document</Style>
    <AuthFlags>0xF</AuthFlags>
</QBWCXML>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? I have made the webservice using ZSI framework.

QBWC Log:

```
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: QBWCService
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): QBWCService
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://localhost:8181/TroubleshootWebServiceFS
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Processing Failure>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.1.0.30">
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Processing Failure>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QBWCService', username = 'username'
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="username"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Processing Failure
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20150629.15:43:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: If you have disabled SSL v3.0 or TLS 1.0 on the system, QBWC will not connect.

Comment: @Keith I have placed the QBWC log in my question. It is giving Processing Failure error. I am not sure what exactly is the problem.

Comment: If you visit http://localhost:8181/TroubleshootWebServiceFS in a browser, what do you see?   Also, turn on VERBOSE logging in the Web Connector http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#setting_the_web_connector_to_use_verbose_logging_mode

Comment: @Keith
I tried to send a post request to my web service through Postman Plugin in Google Chrome. The service returns response in this case. Is there any way I can check the SOAP requests sent by quickbooks web connector?

Comment: Is VERBOSE logging enabled? What did the SOAP response look like when you fudged it through Postman?